# How to configure NICedit to display only "New Window" option?

Tags: configuration, nicedit

I am using NicEdit in my project. I need to disable the option "Current Window" for links in one particular module. How can this be achieved?

Thank You,
Santhosh

Answer (score 0):

Open the nicEdit.js file and Check the line which starts with 
var nicLinkButton=nicEditorAdvancedButton.extend({addPane:function()

in that line find this word "Current Window" and remove the entire word ("":"Current Window",). It will removes the current window option in the nicEdit. Then save your file and check in the browser.

It will work.